# Using like pattern in mysql case statement with two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql-like, mysql-error-1064, procedures, routines

I have a table with names (`names`).  I have another that holds ids (`user`).
I have a conditional construct - a case-when statement that is supposed to insert an id into the user table if a name in the names table matches a certain condition.

I have used `like %` to match string patterns:

```
delimiter //
create procedure name_matching (in names.name varchar, out id int) 
begin  
  case 
    when names.name like 's%_%a' then
      insert into user (id) values ('1'); 
    else
      insert into user (id) values ('2'); 
  end case  
end//
```

This outputs error 1064 on mysql terminal.

Is there a way to do this differently?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of small problems with your procedure. You need a semicolon after the `end case`, you need to specify a field size for the `varchar` in the input parameter list, etc. The following works for me on MySQL 5.1 ("works" meaning: does not produce error when creating procedure):

```
delimiter $$
create procedure name_matching (in name varchar(500)) 
begin
  case
    when name like 's%_%a' then
      insert into user (id) values (1); 
    else
      insert into user (id) values (2); 
  end case;
end $$
```